# HTML5 canvas scrolling on iOS

Tags: ios, html, canvas, touch

I am writing an HTML5 page using the canvas element that will allow users to scroll a large image with their finger using the touch API.  I want to prevent the user from being able to scroll beyond the right and bottom edge of the image.  In other words, I want the scrolling to stop when the user reaches the right or bottom edge of the image.  I have worked out the calculations for doing this and have it working the way I want using a regular web browser.  The problem I am having is that on iOS, large images are being scaled down automatically by the operating system using pixel sampling, and this automatic scaling is interfering with my ability to know the boundaries of the scaled down image.  What I need is a reliable way to know what the true dimensions of the image is, regardless of whether iOS has scaled it down or not.  So far I have been unable to find this out.  Can anyone help me with how to determine this?  I don't really care that iOS has scaled it down, but I need to know the dimensions of the scaled down image so I can know when to stop the user from scrolling past the edge of the image.